# Spreadsheet if else sum

Tags: if-statement, formula, libreoffice-calc

I would appreciate some help writing a statement in a spreadsheet (Libreoffice).

**IF** E4 contains "bought" then do the sum of I4-F4 **ELSE / ELSEIF** E4 contains "sold" do the sum of F4-I4.

I have it partially working: if E4 contains "bought" the correct sum is displayed, but if E4 contains "sold" then #VALUE! is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like:

```
if(exact(e4;"bought");i4-f4;if(exact(e4;"sold");f4-i4))
```

works for you???

Answer (score 0):

Does this formula work as you want:

`=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("bought",E4),0)>0,I4-F4,IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("sold",E4),0)>0,F4-I4,""))`